# How to send one email with multiple records in it

Tags: apex, email, scheduled-apex

I wrote the schedule class for sending an email with lead records(It's going mail with each record) but we need to send one email(based on state) with multiple records created in lead(based on state).

finally output needs "one email with multiple records".

Can you please help me.

```
global class WebtoLeadScheduledProcess implements Schedulable
{

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){ 

   List<Id> webLeadIds =new List<Id>();
  list<lead> webLead1 = [Select Name, Is_Web_Lead__c, WebToLead_User__c, Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c, RecordType.DeveloperName, leadsource,  status, Company, CRS_City__c, CRS_State_Province__C,
                         CRS_Country__c, CRS_Zip__c, Phone, CRS_Application_Type__c, Comments__c, Email, FirstName, CreatedDate  from Lead where CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10];      
      for(Lead l : webLead1)
        webLeadIds.add(l.Id);

  sendMailDistribution(webLeadIds);
 } 

 public static void sendMailDistribution(List<Id> Ids){ 

   CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c mfauser = [Select Id, Name, CRS_W2L_Subject__c, CRS_W2L_CC_Email__c, CRS_W2L_FROM_Email__c from CRS_Web2Lead_Emails__c limit 1];
         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

  list<lead> webLead = [Select Name, Is_Web_Lead__c, WebToLead_User__c, Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c, RecordType.DeveloperName, leadsource,  status, Company, CRS_City__c, CRS_State_Province__C, CRS_Country__c, CRS_Zip__c, 
                          Phone, CRS_Application_Type__c, Comments__c, Email, FirstName, CreatedDate  from Lead where Id IN : Ids and CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10];
         Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> emd = new Map<String, CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c>();
         List<CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c> listCodes = CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c.getAll().values(); 
           OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'Test@example.com'];
              for(CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c c : listCodes){
            emd.put(c.State_Abbreviations__c, c);
           }

  for (Lead l : webLead ){
     if(l.Is_Web_Lead__c == True && l.status == 'open' && l.Cancel_No_Activity_Workflow__c == false && l.leadsource == 'Web Inquiry' && l.WebToLead_User__c == 'QUEUE' && l.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Carrier_Rentals_Lead') {
            CRS_W2L_Email_Distribution_List__c ems = emd.get(l.CRS_State_Province__C);
                  if(ems != null){
                   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                   mail.setSubject('Action required on Unclaimed Lead'); 
                  List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                  for(String key : ems.Email_Distribution_List__c.split(','))
                 {
                        sendTo.add(key);
                 }
                   mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                  mail.setReplyTo(mfauser.CRS_W2L_FROM_Email__c);
                  mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
                  String leadLink = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/' +l.Id;
                   String ecMsg = '<a style=\'color:1B2BE8\' target="_blank" href="'+leadLink+'">'+leadLink+'</a>';
                   String body = 'Hello <br><br>';
                     body += 'Test<br>';
                     body += 'Test.<br><br><br><br>';
                     body += 'Link to the Lead:    '+ecMsg+ '<br><br>';
                     body += 'Thank you. <br><br>';
                     mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                     mail.useSignature = false;
                     mails.add(mail);
             }
          }  
        }

       Messaging.sendEmail(mails);



      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than provide you with the specific code, it seems sufficient to give you the generic details of what needs to be done to do what you're asking. Unfortunately, In a batch or schedulable class, you can't use a "group by" clause in a query.

If your records don't exceed 50,000 you could use a queueable class where you'd be able to use a group by clause to return your query results by state. Otherwise, you'll need to sort your results, most likely using the [comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm%23apex_comparable) to get the results organized by state. To avoid that hassle, I'd recommend going the queueable route if you can, chaining them if necessary to run by state if needed.

The next thing is that you'll need to modify your email methods to use the [mass email messaging class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm%23apex_classes_email_outbound_mass) instead of the single email messaging class. Once you do that, you should be all set.

Comment: My question is simple How to send only one email with different records in that mail. Generally, it will go each mail for each record but am looking for How to send only one email with multiple records.

Comment: Simple answer: you have to use the mass email messaging methods (which extend the single email messaging methods) instead of the single email messaging method only, to which you pass a list of email addresses. Go look at the link in the documentation I referred you to or search the forum for posts on mass email methods. Either will provide you with plenty of examples.

Comment: Can you please take my example of code and explain me. It will be useful for me. Thank you.

Comment: As @crmprogdev suggests, search in the forum. You will get plenty of examples. Read the documentation and examples. I am quite sure you will be able to solve the issue by yourself only. That's the best way. Trust me. crmprogdev already provided you the correct direction.